# visual studio 2022 coplit show:Your current Copilot license doesn't support proxy connections with self-signed certificates

Tags: github-copilot

cant used copilit at visual studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v31C.png)

when i sign in the coplit ,visual studio ,shows error, "show:Your current Copilot license doesn't support proxy connections with self-signed certificates."

how to fix it ,I

Answer (score 5):

Solution found in some post on github but you might find it useful:

- Open Edge browser and navigate to github.com
- Open certificate details (icon left to page URL) then go to second tab in cert viewer
- Export cert - save as chain (choose 'save as type'[chain - second in the list] in a 'save as' window) - it should be in PEM format (type extension manually)

Add system variable (NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS) with path to the PEM file.

Start Visual Studio 2022 and it should fly.

Comment: Confirmed working!  Does not work without the "chain - second in the list"!  Thank you!